# How do you deal with zeros in time series analysis?

Tags: python, statistics, data-analysis, analysis

Hi I am a data analyst that recently moved on to looking at some time series analysis for Covid-19 risks. I have a large financial dataset that contains the bank account balance of customers (both Business' and Personal) for the past 5 years.

I am looking to do some time series analysis on this so I split the data into two datasets, Business and personal, I want to see if less money is coming in then before and if I can target specific customers with higher decreases.

I got the month on month percentage change using python and built out a dataset of the month on month percentage changes. The problem here is I noticed many customers have 0 balance for sporadic months throughout the year, this makes the % change -100%/+100% and skews the data significantly.

Does anyone have any advice on dealing with the 0 data in this context and any suggestions on how I can visually represent the data so that it is still representative

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: If it's really just sporadic, e.g. `<many months of balances>, <some 0 month(s)>, <many months of balances>`, I might linearly interpolate between the months surrounding the 0 month(s). Your question, however, is better asked on [stats.SE].

Comment: If you want to see if less money is coming into the accounts than before, percent change in balance is the wrong metric.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I actually didnt know that existed. Yes it is very sporadic, possibly will cross post there but I will investigate the linear interpolation first

Comment: You can also focus on moving average values , daily average deposits etc.